# How to compile caffe without next error "libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'"

Tags: opencv, cmake, caffe

I've seen many solutions for that problem but no one helped me.
I've tried to add `opencv_imgcodecs` in **Makefile**, use `cmake` etc.

**Makefile.config**

```
CPU_ONLY := 1
OPENCV_VERSION := 3
CUSTOM_CXX := g++
CUDA_DIR := /usr/local/cuda
CUDA_ARCH := -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 \
        -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 \
        -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
        -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
        -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
        -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 \
        -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 \
        -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 \
        -gencode arch=compute_61,code=compute_61

BLAS := atlas
PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python2.7 \
        /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
PYTHON_LIB := /usr/lib
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/include/hdf5/serial
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial
BUILD_DIR := build
DISTRIBUTE_DIR := distribute
TEST_GPUID := 0
Q ?= @
```

when I execute `make all` I receive next error in output:

```
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/extract_features.bin
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cv::imencode(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:635: recipe for target '.build_release/tools/extract_features.bin' failed
make: *** [.build_release/tools/extract_features.bin] Error 1
```

Ubuntu 18.04.
That was the last guide I used [Here](https://gist.github.com/nikitametha/c54e1abecff7ab53896270509da80215)

Judging by the output:

```
AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0
CXX tools/extract_features.cpp
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/extract_features.bin
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
```

it seems that we are going to dynamic library `libcaffe.so` and right after we use it to interact with `extract_features.bin`. If you were to learn what `libcaffe.so` compiled from, perhaps it would be possible to include an OpenCV connection in any of the source files.
But how to determine the source files for creating `libcaffe.so` I cannot understand.
I tried to look in the Makefile, feeling as if he was obfuscated, nothing is clear.

Comment: a little advice?

Comment: faced the same issue? any solution @AlmostAI

Comment: @KhanHafizurRahman added solution for my case

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related with opencv version.
I quote:

> the error is not about how to compile, nothing happens if we change
> the Makefile or CMakeLists.txt. The error caused by the OpenCV module
> in version 3 and 4 has change.
>
> to fix it, in every file that error to build:
>
> in the section #ifdef USE_OPENCV, add:
>
> #include "opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp"
>
> so it will looks like this:
>
> #ifdef USE_OPENCV
> #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
> #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
> #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h>
> #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
> #include "opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp" then, the file which has code: cv_img = cv::imread(image.first, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
>
> change to: cv_img = cv::imread(image.first,cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
>
> and the other files which has:
>
> int cv_read_flag = (is_color ? CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR :
> CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE); change to:
>
> int cv_read_flag = (is_color ? cv::IMREAD_COLOR :
> cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

The solution was found [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/6680#issuecomment-622989343).